# If $(x, y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$, does $|(x, y)|\ge\frac12 (|x| +|y|)$ hold true?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, inequality

Let $x, y\in\mathbb{R}$ and consider the couple $(x, y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$. I' m trying to understand if the relation
$$|(x, y)|\ge\frac12 (|x| +|y|)$$
holds true where $|(x, y)|$ denotes the euclidean norm in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Could someone please help me proving that? Or instead provide a counterexample?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What happens if $x=y$? Does $\sqrt2 \ge \frac32$?

Comment: Can you precise the norm $\lvert (x, y) \rvert$ you're using?  And you mean $\frac12 |x| +|y|$ not $\frac{1}{2} \left(\lvert x \rvert + \lvert y \rvert \right)$?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net question edited, thank you for your useful comment.

Comment: Try to write the Eucledian norm explicitly, you will obtain an inequality involving square roots and absolute values. To treat the square root you can raise both sides to the second power since both members are positive. Can you continue from that point?

Comment: I would view this problem as a question about triangles.  Perhaps trying to realize it in that way will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have

$$\begin{aligned}
4(x^2 + y^2 ) - \left(\lvert x \rvert + \lvert y \rvert\right)^2 &=
2(x^2 + y^2 ) + 2(x^2 + y^2 )- \left(\lvert x \rvert + \lvert y \rvert\right)^2\\
&\ge 2(x^2 + y^2 )- \left(\lvert x \rvert + \lvert y \rvert\right)^2\\
&= \left(\lvert x \rvert - \lvert y \rvert\right)^2 \ge 0
\end{aligned}$$

hence the desired result. In fact $\alpha = \sqrt 2$ is the best constant for the inequality
$$|(x, y)|\ge\frac{1}{\alpha} (|x| +|y|)$$ to hold.

Answer (score 1):

Setting $x+y=a, \frac xa=p, \frac ya=q, x, y\ge0$ is enough by symmetry and $|k||a|=|ka|$ holds in Euclidean metric. Then your inequality changes into $|(p, q)|\ge \frac12$...

$$
|(p, q)|^2=p^2+q^2=p^2+(1-p)^2=2p^2-2p+1=\frac12(2p-1)^2+\frac12\ge\frac12>\frac14
$$